# Trying to simplify my Python codes but shows syntax error: variable not defined

Tags: python, loops

I was trying to simplify this:

```
def get_average(name):
    homework=average(name["homework"])   
    quizzes=average(name["quizzes"])     
    tests=average(name["tests"])
    weighted_mark= homework *0.1+ quizzes*0.3 + tests*0.6
    return weighted_mark
```

So I use a loop:

```
def get_average(name):
    component = ["homework","quizzes","tests"]
    for thing in component:
        thing = average(name[thing])
    weighted_mark= homework *0.1+ quizzes*0.3 + tests*0.6
    return weighted_mark
```

But the console shows syntax error: **variable "homework" not defined**. 
Doesn't
`thing = average(name[thing])`
defined the variables?

This is the [dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hitO.png) that I worked with

Comment: No, it defines a variable called "thing".

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh! Thank you! So is there another way to simplify it?

Comment: The first code seems  simple enough already.

Comment: What's wrong with `return average(name['homework']) * 0.1 + average(...) ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create variables like that. `thing = 2` will always leave you with a variable named `thing`, it doesn't matter what that name was pointing to before.

Since you don't have the coefficients structured, you still need to enumerate the three components during the print. If you want to get rid of this, you could create a dict:

```
weights = {
    "homework": 0.1,
    "quizzes": 0.3,
    "tests": 0.6,
}
```

and then use it like this

```
weighted_mark = sum(average(name[thing]) * weights[thing] for thing in weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the variables. For that propouse, you can do 2 things: Declare variables from a list, or use a dictionary.

If you want to create variables on the fly you can use `globals()[]`:

```
for x in component:
    globals()[x] = average(name[x])
```

If you want to create a dict, do the next:

```
resultado = dict()
for x in component:
     resultado[x] = average(name[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would connect both weights and components via dictionary. Then in a loop calculate weighted mark.

```
def get_average(name):
        component = {"homework":0.1, "quizzes":0.3, "tests":0.6}
        weighted_mark = 0
        for thing in component:
                weighted_mark = weighted_mark + average(name[thing]) * component[thing]
        return weighted_mark
```